# Akka-Cluster-Sharding: local ShardRegion(system).shardRegion(_)

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

I have a master Actor responsible for initializing some worker actors (there are two types of worker actors, namely, ParamServer actor and DataShard actor). For example, if I initiated 20 datashard actors via `ClusterSharding(system).start(_,_,_,_,_)` and after that I want to send some message to all datashard actors (say `case object ReadyToProcess`). I read that I can send messages to entities in Akka Cluster Shard via local `ShardRegion(system).shardRegion(_)`. Is local **shardRegion(_)** will send to all datashards or just one. How can I send msgs to all datashard actors?
The master class given be:

```
class Master(ports: Seq[String],
         dataSet: Seq[Example],
         dataPerReplica: Int,
         layerDimensions: Seq[Int],
         activation: ActivationFunction,
         activationFunctionDer: ActivationFunction,
         learningRate: Double) extends Actor with ActorLogging  {

val dataShards = dataSet.grouped(dataPerReplica).toSeq
val numLayers = layerDimensions.size
var numShardsFinished = 0

ports foreach { port =>

  val config = ConfigFactory.parseString("akka.remote.netty.tcp.port=" + port).withFallback(ConfigFactory.load())
  val clusterSystem = ActorSystem("ClusterSystem", config)

  val paramServerRegions: Array[ActorRef] = new Array[ActorRef](numLayers - 1)

  for (i <- 0 to numLayers - 2) {

    paramServerRegions(i) = ClusterSharding(clusterSystem).start(
      typeName = ParamServer.shardName,
      entityProps = ParamServer.props(i, dataShards.size, learningRate, NeuralNetworkOps.randomMatrix(layerDimensions(i + 1), layerDimensions(i) + 1)),
      settings = ClusterShardingSettings(clusterSystem),
      extractEntityId = ParamServer.extractEntityId,
      extractShardId = ParamServer.extractShardId
    )
  }

  //create actors for each data shard/replica.  Each replica needs to know about all parameter shards because they will
  //be reading from them and updating them
  val dataShardRegions: Array[ActorRef] = new Array[ActorRef](dataShards.size)

  for (i <- 0 to dataShards.size) {

    dataShardRegions(i) = ClusterSharding(clusterSystem).start(
      typeName = DataShard.shardName,
      entityProps = DataShard.props(i, clusterSystem, dataShards(i), activation, activationFunctionDer, paramServerRegions),
      settings = ClusterShardingSettings(clusterSystem),
      extractEntityId = ParamServer.extractEntityId,
      extractShardId = ParamServer.extractShardId
    )
  }

}

def receive: Receive = {

case Start => {
  val shardRegionSender =   ClusterSharding(context.system).shardRegion(DataShard.shardName)
  println("Tomosha boshlandi")
  shardRegionSender ! ReadyToProcess
}

case ShardDone(id) => {

    numShardsFinished+=1
    log.info("")

    if (numShardsFinished == dataShards.size) {
        context.parent ! JobDone
        context.stop(self)
    }
}
}

}
```